# Understanding what equipment I need for my Specific Needs

Tags: mixer, daw, surround-sound, reaper, console

I hope this doesn't appear to be a shopping recommendation question because I already have a starting basis for what I need from having taken an audio fundamentals and DAW course.

But I'm wondering if the following pieces of equipment I have are going to be compatible with each other given how much technology has changed. I am on an extremely low budget, so I am getting everything secondhand from pawn shops and sites like eBay or neighbourhood social media.

I currently have a Behringer Xenyx-1622FX USB analogue Mixer, a phantom powering box and one XLR cable. Just today, I got a Sony STR DE425 receiver. Just a few days ago, I learnt that this receiver is about 22 years old. Many of today's receivers dont' use wire clamps or phono connectors (those RCA plugs that come in pairs or stuff like that.) Anyhow, they use optical and HDMI, although they might still use AV, composite, or SCART, but that's mostly for the 5.1 speakers.

This particular receiver is supposed to have a radio (tuner), stereo, amplifier, and Dolby Surround Sound receiver.

If I want to DJ live and/or create surround sound projects with my DAW, will these pieces of equipment work together for what I need it to do? A WikiHow article I read said that I would need an amplifier to connect the speakers to, as connecting the speakers directly to the mixer wouldn't suffice even though it is a powered mixer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a phantom powering box

You don't need that. The 1622-FX has a built-in Phantom power. You should ONLY use this if you have a condenser microphone that actually needs it. Dynamic mics are typically a lot cheaper and sturdier and don't need Phantom power.

> and one XLR cable

What do you want to use it for ?

> even though it is a powered mixer.

It's not. It plugs into the wall but it doesn't have power amplifiers in the mixer itself.

> If I want to DJ live and/or create surround sound projects with my DAW, will these pieces of equipment work together for what I need it to do?

Depends on the size of your venue. The Sony receiver contains typical consumer grade amplifiers. This may work ok in a small residential setting, i.e. a few people in a living room or basement. It's not going to work for anything bigger and it's also likely to wear out and break if used for live sound.

The most important part of a setup would be the speaker themselves, which you haven't mentioned. It would be easiest if you get a pair of powered speakers and hook them directly to the mixer.

Initially I would stick with stereo. Surround sound requires more speaker and way more complexity in the mixing/production chain.

Comment: A guy I met on next-door offered the phantom power box along with one extra large cable, and initially they were going to give me a receiver, but it got sold. I’m keeping the XLR cable in case they get a microphone that you just XLR. Also, is a direct box the same as a power amplifier? I understand a mixture of power to power the preamplifiers, if they have one built in, or otherwise did you use an external train preamplifier.

Comment: I don’t know if this would help, but I am completely blind and have almost 10 years of single truck editing experience, and about four or five years of multi track editing experience, although I’ve never been able to afford professional audio gear until now. So, that is why I am interested in learning all I can about using surround sound I have a lot of effort has been made to make digital audio workstation acceptable to blind individuals, since many like to experiment with sound design.

Comment: Surround sound is more complicated since it has more channels. Typically 5 or 6 instead of 2. That means you need 5 speakers, 5 speaker cables, 5 speaker stands and room to place all this. Your mixer may not have enough outputs. You may be able to use Subgroups of the 1622-FX has them. At least it looks like the Sont Receiver has 6 discrete inputs for surround sound, so that helps. Do you just want to do this at home or do you actually want to do DJ gigs at other places ?

Comment: Literally, I want to have something at home to practice with, so that way to get more familiar rise with my set up before actually doing DJ gigs. But yes, when I do you search gigs, I would like to be more prepared for what I will need, such as getting powered speakers as you mentioned. I was also going to ask for clarification on how to know whether an amplifier is consumer grade, or if it is heavy duty. But yes, I do have some knowledge in automation and stuff like that.